# How to split a string like 45frank using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I have a section of my site where I use check boxes to show hide informational divs onclick.
I need to be able to toggle a continue button as well as the hidden divs(show/hide) or (toggle) while gathering the 2 digits at the front of the string to use as an ID when adding to cart. I thought maybe the jquery split() function with reg exp. How can I split a string like 45frank, so it would be something like id=45 and val=frank.

Comment: would be better to split the id like "45_frank", much easier to parse latter.

Comment: unfortunately, I am working with an existing system, and the vars are already set, I would have used the 45_frank format, This is why I asked the question. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var str = "45frank";

var parts = str.match(/(\d+)(\D+)/).slice(1);
```

This assumes the second part will not contain any numbers.

It returns an array:

```
["45", "frank"]
```

If it is possible that the second part could have a number, you could do this instead:

```
var str = "45fr9ank";

var parts = str.match(/(\d+)(\D.+)/).slice(1);
```

resulting in:

```
["45", "fr9ank"]
```

Then just add the text you want:

```
parts[0] = "id=" + parts[0]
parts[1] = "val=" + parts[1]
```

---

Or if you wanted a single string result (I can't tell from the question) you can do this:

```
var str = "45fr9ank";

str = str.replace(/(\d+)(\D.+)/,function(str,s1,s2){ 
             return "id=" + s1 + " val=" + s2; 
});
```

results in:

```
"id=45 val=fr9ank"
```

Comment: +1 For the example with the callback function in replace. I wasn't aware of that possibility.

Comment: mention that `\D` is a non-digit. `\d` being a digit is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = string.slice(0,2);
var val = string.substr(2);
```

There's no reason to use jQuery or regular expressions here. This only works if the number is always two digits.

If you forgot it as "45#Frank" then you can use something like

```
var id = string.split("#")[0];
var val = string.split("#")[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however the digit part is an auto-incrementing DB field, as such it may grow to 3 digits also, Your response is correct for the limited info I gave.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I try to not use reg exp as often because of performance hit. If your string is of a format 2 digits then bunch of characters. You can try to access the string as an array. Unfortunately IE doesn't support this. But I have a work around which basically convert the string into an array access the first two digit and undo it. Just use javascript built in function, I believe it was .split(). Unfortunately I don't have the code on me right now.

But you basically convert the string to array. Access [0] and [1] for the digit. From [2] to... the string length minus one would be your char string. You can convert an array back to a string again with another javascript built in function. The reasoning to this madness is because IE doesn't support accessing string like an array.

That's how I did it. Or just use a HTML5 custom attribute, data-, to put the info separately.